# Cannot get value of Observable in Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to create my own observable in Knockout but I'm having trouble getting it to work correctly. Here is the code:

```
ko.extenders.trackChange = function (target, track) {
    if (track) {
        target.isDirty = ko.observable(false);
        console.log('inventory: ' + target.isDirty());
        target.originalValue = target();
        target.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            target.isDirty(newValue != target.originalValue);
        });
    }
    return target;
};
```

And this is one that I'm calling from another file:

```
saveOnLoseFocus = () => {
        console.log(this.firstIncrease.subscribe(function () {
            return this.firstIncrease.isDirty();
        }));
}
```

However, it is saying that it cannot find the fuction isDirty(). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you `applyBindings()`?  Have you loaded the JS file that defines the variables before the other one that calls them?

Comment: Yes. I have another extension called numeric that rounds the value to the set decimal place. That seems to work but not trackChange.

Comment: you dont need `subscriber` since `isDirty` is also an observable. so try it like `console.log(this.firstIncrease.isDirty());`

Comment: The binding looks fine; the problem is probably some where else in your code. Any chance you can share more of it? How are you using the extension? Are you initializing it more than once? What does your binding context look like when you're checking isDirty?

Comment: @JAG you're right that this.firstIncrease.isDirty() is all I needed. The IDE was saying it was a syntax error and wouldn't let me compile the project which is why I thought it was wrong.

Comment: ok, try it with regular function like `saveOnLoseFocus = function () { console.log(this.firstIncrease.isDirty()); }`